# Mapping values from a List of Either to List

Tags: scala, loops, syntactic-sugar, either

I have two lists one is:

```
val l1 = List[Either[A,B]]
```

and

```
val l2 = List[String]
```

Now, all I need to do is map these two. i.e., if `l1` is A then return corresponding value from `l2`. Tried something like:

```
for {
   elem1  <- l1
   elem2  <- l2
   result <- if(elem1.isLeft) url
} yield result
```

This doesn't work. Because, I am not handling the `else` case. Similarly with match instead of `if`. How do I go about to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (I'm assuming `l2` has at least the same number of elements of type `A` as `Left`s in `l1`):

```
val result: List[String] = l1.zip(l2).filter(_._1.isLeft).map(_._2)
```

Otherwise, if you prefer using `for`, this will also do the trick:

```
scala> for {
 |   e1 <- l1.zip(l2)
 |   if e1._1.isLeft
 | } yield e1._2
```

Comment: Yes they do. Didn't know about this zip option, strange that it didn't come up in search as well. Elegant.